# calculate time in merging lcuene indexes

Tags: java, merge, lucene, indexing

I am merging lucene indexes with the help of java programs .Merging of indexing is being done fine but i also want to display the waiting time to merge the indexes .So is there any ,method
to calculate the time taken to merge the indexes or suggest any alternate actually i want to show the progress bar which will show the approximate time taken to merge the indexes.
For merging the index i am using the following code.

```
 try{
 File INDEX_DIR= new File("D:\\merge lucene\\abc\\");
 INDEX_DIR.mkdir();
 File indexDir = new File("D:\\merge lucene\\abc\\");
 Directory indexes[] = new Directory[indexDir.list().length];
 IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(
 FSDirectory.open(INDEX_DIR),
 new SimpleAnalyzer(),true,
 IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED); 
 indexes[0] = FSDirectory.open(indexDir);
 writer.addIndexes(indexes[0]); 
 File indexDir1 = new File("D:\\merge lucene\\def\\");
 Directory indexes1[] = new Directory[indexDir1.list().length];
 indexes1[0] = FSDirectory.open(indexDir1);
 writer.addIndexes(indexes1[0]);
 writer.optimize();
 writer.close();   
 System.out.println("index merged");


} 


    catch(Exception ex){System.out.println("exception here"+ex);}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately in my knowledge there does not exist any API which might provide you the time required for merging.. You can try asking this same question on the lucene user mailing list..

**java-user@lucene.apache.org**

However, the **code snippet provided is incorrect**. **You are not closing all the resources properly**. All the opened directory should be closed. You should also close the analyzer. Not closing the resources will have an impact on the indexing result. Also if any **index deletion** is supposed to happen, not closing the resources will fail index deletion also..

Its a better way to close the resource in finally block so that even if exception occur, you have ensured that all resources are properly closed.